# Why isn't the book-recommendations tag a synonym for reference-request?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

I recently noticed the [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) tag and I've been wondering why it isn't a synonym for the [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag. All I could find here on Meta is <strike>that it [used](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books) to be so</strike> when it was created, but I couldn't find *why* it was made separate from [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

**Edit:** <strike>I agree with Martin Sleziak, so I'm leaving this question open to allow further discussion.</strike> I posted a proposal to merge [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and [textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbooks) with [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20139/65389), though.

**Edit2:** A [quick search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+is%3Aquestion) shows that only [about two thirds](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+-book+-books+-textbook+-textbooks+is%3Aquestion) of the questions currently tagged [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) are about books. Therefore I'm dropping the proposal for merging [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) with it and I'm accepting AlexR's answer.

Comment: Re: *it used to be so*. No. The thread [you linked to](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books) is precisely the thread which lead to creating ([tag:book-recommendation]). (You may notice that in the answers there users voted whether this tag should be created. So it was created after that question was posted.) Both ([tag:books]) and ([tag:textbooks]) were already [synonyms of (reference-request)](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/synonyms) at the time.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The first comment to the question I linked to, posted 9 minutes after the question itself,  is "It already exists, but is a synonym for reference-request".  Did I misunderstand this and it was actually referred to [tag:books]?

Comment: Yes, that particular comment refers to the ([tag:books]) tag. You can see from  [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books#comment53563_13593) when ([tag:book-recommendation]) tag was created.

Comment: Shouldn't this be part of the tag management post?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015

Comment: @dustin I think it's ok to have a separate post about a tag. The post you linked says: *"Of course if a proposal requires an extended discussion you can post it as a separate question."*

Comment: @MartinSleziak It would be better to first post there and _then_ ask a separate discussion question _if_ the need for such arises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that a [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) is a recommendation of material, usually for *learning* about a particular subject while a [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) may ask for a source where theorem $X$ is proved. So there is a difference between their meaning.
As to the synonyms, I agree with out that they should be made synonym of [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) instead, especially [textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbooks) seems more related to it than to [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).